# Crear llaves primarias en una tabla usando hash

Tags: base-de-datos, tablas, hash, sha256

Esto no es para un proyecto, es más una curiosidad.

1. Supongamos que se quiera hacer una tabla con registros de animales, con tres campos básicos como id, nombre_cientifico, nombre_comun.
2. Tener en cuenta que las especies animales no son miles, sino millones y cada cierto tiempo se descubren nuevas especies.
3. En lugar de generar una llave autoincrementada, o alfanúmerica de longitud variable, se registraría la llave primaria (id) con el hash (SHA-256) del nombre_cientifico.

Por ejemplo, en lugar de que sea:

| id | nombre_cientifico | nombre_comun |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Canis lupus | Lobo |
| 2 | Canis lupus familiaris | Perro |

Sería:

| id | nombre_cientifico | nombre_comun |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71C1049D1303D2824D5CB82C340A6B4F130DAC805E27B5104F6A477EC5EE4916 | Canis lupus | Lobo |
| 15460A0B65C0DA463E1FB2F133FC34E3AA1A0128DF58E2C68F8B530AAFA22A1B | Canis lupus familiaris | Perro |

El fin sería que no se genere un orden numérico, sino un código único y difícilmente repetible, es por ello que se usaría un hash.

Esto podría generar mucho almacenamiento en la BD. Sin embargo, quisiera conocer si han visto casos similares usando hash. Además, que ventajas y desventajas traería esto.

PD: Sé que el hash no está ideado para esto, pero el requisito es que las llaves:

- No tengan orden numérico
- La llave sea irrepetible
- Todas las llaves deben tener la misma longitud.

Comment: afortunadamente no, pero obviamente el performance sería deplorable

Comment: Qué alternativa propondrías que cumplan estos requisitos?

- No tengan orden numérico
- La llave sea irrepetible (se sobreentiende)
- Todas las llaves deben tener la misma longitud.